# WordPress hosting on AWS using three tier architecture

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, networking, three-tier

I am trying to implementing wordpress website using three tier architecture on AWS for my educational purpose. I had created MySQL database instance and one ec2 instance for wordpress website. As per AWS three tier [documentation](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-web-hosting-best-practices.pdf) there are three tiers first one is web server, second one is application server and third one is DB server.

I am confused between web server and app server. I am trying to build wordpress application that makes use of all these three layers.

As per research and I read document which i mentioned above, web server deals with only static data, while app server contains main business logic and having connection with DB server and return data to client.

I am confused where to host wordpress site on web server or app server and also, how these three layers are interconnected.

Please help me if there is any tutorial available for application hosting using three tier architecture on AWS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are official AWS white papers devoted to hosting WordPress. Most notably:

- [WordPress: Best Practices on AWS](http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/wordpress-best-practices-on-aws.pdf)
- [Deploying WordPress with AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/deploying-wordpress-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk.pdf)

In the first one, you can find the following architecture diagram:

[image]

As it can be seen, it is also 3 tier architecture. However, in the first tier, you have only NAT gateways. There is **no dedicated web and app tiers**. Entire WorPress is hosted in the second tier, with DB in the third tier.

The key things to note are the use of **RDS and EFS**. By its nature, WordPress is **not stateless**. But with help of RDS and EFS, it can successfully work in AutoScaling Group (ASG). ASG requires stateless servers.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I read your comments. As I am beginner, can you please provide information on where to host wordpress site on web server or app server and also, how web server, app server and database are interconnected.

Comment: @dharmeshchaudhary I recommend to read the white papers carefully. Everything is explained there. There are also many more tutorials which explain these topics online.